# Is there a way to hyperlink particular words to another URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am working on Cargo Collective's custom HTML for my website. I wanted to have this randomized text on my homepage/landing page that highlights some of my projects
Also, I wanted each project name to be underlined and hyperlinked to the actual project page of the website.

I used the array method to create the text selector -- how can I do the hyperlink and the underline part within the same script?

Or if there's another way to achieve this, what could that be?

This is the JS I am using:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function random_textDisplay(){

    var mytext=new Array()

    mytext[1]="Jigyasa Tuli is constantly speculating about the nuance of language and how to make mango pickle."
    mytext[2]="Jigyasa Tuli absolutely loves Daft Punk and making weird but profound bulb analogies."
    mytext[3]="Jigyasa Tuli is ? + &#128293;"


var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*mytext.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<h1>'+mytext[ry]+'</h1>')
}
random_textDisplay()
```

So, take any one of these sentences in the array.
For example, take mytext[1]. If I wanted to underline and hyperlink just 'the nuance of language', how would I go about that?

Comment: There's loads of ways to do this. A text string:URL dictionary is one example. Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `<a href="url">text</a>` around the text that you would like to be the hyperlink. If you'd rather it not open in a new tab, remove `target="_blank"`.

```js
function random_textDisplay(){
    var mytext=new Array()

    mytext[1]="Jigyasa Tuli is constantly speculating about the <a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com'>nuance of language</a> and how to make mango pickle."
    mytext[2]="Jigyasa Tuli absolutely loves Daft Punk and making weird but profound bulb analogies."
    mytext[3]="Jigyasa Tuli is ? + &#128293;"

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*mytext.length)
    if (ry==0)
        ry=1
    document.write('<h1>'+mytext[ry]+'</h1>')
}
random_textDisplay()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Kind of embarrassed. But I definitely got confused between the double quote marks and if putting a tag in there would be recognized as text itself.

Comment: Haha no worries. I couldn't remember if tags were rendered either, so I just tested it :)